# warning about C function pointer

Tags: c, warnings

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*func_t)(void * data);

void func2(int * arg, func_t free_func) {
        free_func(arg);
}

void func(int * a) {
        printf("%d\n", *a);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
        int a = 4;
        func2(&a, func);
        return 0;
}
```

Compiling which gives me 
warning: passing arg 2 of `func2' from incompatible pointer type

Why is that?  Shouldn't int pointer be compatible with void pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
free_func((int *)arg);
```

Note though that converting a void * to T* (in this case int*) 
 is **unsafe** due to the side-effects of using a T* that is not actually pointing to a T

e.g.

```
char i = 0;
char j = 0;    
char* p = &i;
void* q = p;
int* pp = q;    /* unsafe, legal C, not C++ */
printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
*pp = -1;   /* overwrite memory starting at &i */
 printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
```

Answer (score 3):

That you can cast the types doesn't mean the compiler will happily do so for you.

In this case the function pointer definition doesn't match up.  C is not going to assume that a function declared to take `int*` will be happy instead with a `void*`, even though the conversion between those two types is implicit.  This is a subtle gotcha in how C handles function pointers.

If you want this to work without warnings, you will have to cast like so:

```
func2(%a, (func_t)func);
```

Comment: OK, so conversion between types is implicit, but between function signatures involving these types is not implicit?  Counter intuitive.

Comment: That's the gist of it.  Yeah, I never said C was intuitive.  ;)

Comment: I also do not understand why I never ran into this before... Might have something to do with the fact that VC++ doesn't complain about it.

Comment: That's entirely possible.  Different C compilers use a different set of warnings by default, and may not even operate in any sort of "spec-compliant" mode either, unless explicitly requested.  This highlights the reason why you should test that your code compiles on all of the platforms/compilers you support, since subtle differences like this can bite you.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer types are compatible only if their base types are compatible, and `int` and `void` are not compatible.

Furthermore, it is possible for int and void pointers to have different sizes and representations.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the declaration / definition of func to

```
void func(void * a) {
        printf("%d\n", *(int*)a);
}
```

everything works as you'd expect.